# compare key.name to a string of a json response

Tags: c#, json, key-value

I have the below json:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "/subscriptions/5a9c0639-4045-4c23-8418-fc091e8d1e31/resourceGroups/citrix-xd-0ec69105-c451-4676-8723-97932bf4d94a-ayjzs",
            "name": "citrix-xd-0ec69105-c451-4676-8723-97932bf4d94a-ayjzs",
            "location": "australiaeast",
            "tags": {
                "CitrixResource": "Internal",
                "CitrixSchemaVersion": "2.0",
                "CitrixProvisioningSchemeId": "0ec69105-c451-4676-8723-97932bf4d94a",
                "BillTo": "O1001396_8796-SS-Citrix",
                "Reference Name": "Citrix POC"
            },
            "properties": {
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
            }
        }
]
```

note : the above json is just a part of a big json array

I want to read specific 'tags' node and compare the 'key name' e.g. `CitrixResource` to a string and say if it is not same then fail.

so far I have done below:

```
JObject jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(result);
result = jsonParsed["value"].ToString()
var Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AzureResponse>>(result);
foreach (var AzureResponse in Response)
{
    //do something

    //and say
    {
        if (Tags.citrixResource.Propertyname = "name")
        {
            then pass;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you have any tags (FooResource, CiscoNotResource, etc) or are you trying to see of that specific tag is set. These are two quite different things

Comment: basically i want to read all the node name 'Tags' and check for the child values as here it is "CitrixResource'' and compare with a string say "refer name" and as they both are not same it should fail.

Answer (score 0):

**Deserialize the json `result`**

```
  var jsonParsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);
```

**Converting the property `value` inside the `json` to `List<AzureResponse>`**

```
  //if the json is an object with `value` as property inside it
  var result = jsonParsed["value"].ToString();

  //if the `value` is an array of format `List<AzureResponse>`
  List<AzureResponse> AzureResponseList= new List<AzureResponse>();
  JsonConvert.PopulateObject(result, AzureResponseList);
```

**Using `Linq queries` to loop through the list**

```
  //then using `linq` we could query according to our needs
  var tag=AzureResponseList.Where(x=>x.tags['CitrixResource']=='name').FirstOrDefault();
```

**Or Using `foreach` to loop through the list**

```
//example with foreach
foreach(var response in AzureResponseList){
   if(response.tags['CitrixResource']=='name'){
     //do something
   }
}
```

**If we don't want to convert to any models , we could directly use the `jsonParsed` dynamic object**

```
  //without converting to some models we could directly use the jsonParsed 
  foreach(var response in jsonParsed ){
     if(response.tags['CitrixResource']=='name'){
         //do something
     }
  }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for this , is their any way to run it in a loop and compare all the child keys, in place of 'CitrixResource' i want to say tags.firstchild.PropertyName? is it possible?